# mPDF cuts the contents of the column

Tags: php, html, mpdf

First code:

```
$mpdf = new MPDF('','',0,'',15,15,5,5);

$mpdf->AddPage('P','A4'); 
$mpdf->SetColumns(2,'',1); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML('
<table style="width:326px;background:none;border-width:1px;border-style: dotted;border-color:grey;padding:8px;">  
   <tr>
   <td>
....the contents of the table number 1.....
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>

', 0);     

$mpdf->WriteHTML('
<table style="width:326px;background:none;border-width:1px;border-style: dotted;border-color:grey;padding:8px;">  
   <tr>
   <td>
....the contents of the table number 2.....
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>

', 0);
```

I want to generate a PDF-based form php. Ultimately, the data to be displayed in tables, each table will contain
records of the loop. Thus, the display will be as many tables, how many records.
I can not come to terms with the display tables. I want them to show up one after the other
in two columns, from top to bottom, four tables on page A4.
At the moment displays the tables 1 in the left column, and 2 tables on the right (in the right column does not respond to the upper margin).
Tables are such a height that defo fit two vertically.
Is mPDF that is?
Please help!
see photo below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

found solution to not break table use style="page-break-inside:avoid;" but it shows tables of loop in single col. but i also want to display in two col, got any solution then pl share..